# R: Make sure default argument is evaluated early

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

When providing a default argument to an R function, this argument is evaluated when first used in the function. How is it possible to evaluate default argument earlier in an elegant way? Example:

```
f <- function(x, y = 2 * x)
{
  if(x < 0) x = 10
  y
}

f(1) ## Returns 2
f(-1) ## Returns 20 but I would like it to return -2
```

Thanks

Comment: Add `force(y)` at the beginning of the function. However, I don't understand what you are doing (a function that just returns the second argument regardless the value of the first, making a useless assignment in the process seems pretty strange).

Answer (score 1):

The answer wasn't to hard to find. The function 'force' does the trick:

```
f <- function(x, y = 2 * x)
{
  force(y)
  if(x < 0) x = 10
  y
}

f(1) ## Returns 2
f(-1) ## -2
```